# Playing Audio files in chunks and downloading

Tags: android, performance, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

Hey #AndroidDev community! I am Working on a project where I'm downloading audio files from a server and storing them locally and then playing that audio file. Now, I'm exploring ways to implement a progressive download and play feature for these audio files. The goal is to start playing as soon as a chunk is downloaded and seamlessly update the playback as more data becomes available.

Any insights, best practices you could share to achieve this dynamic streaming?